# Add Company Name column to Woocommerce Analytics - Orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not really sure what that is not an option. Customer name is not as important for me as the billing company name. Why is it omitted from analytics, beats me.

I would like to add a column in Analytics -> Orders that displays company names.

Any ideas?

Fiddled with woocommerce settings, couldn't find anything.

Comment: Those Analytics pages are rendered using ReactJS code, so I am unsure if you can make any customization on those pages. It will be good to confirm with the WooCommerce support forum if customization is possible on those pages or not.